# How to automatically find files of a specified type in the current directory or any specified sub-folders in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, automation, build-automation, rake, rakefile

I am using the following code to convert files from php to html. In order for it to work, I have to enter the name of each file on the second line.

```
p "convert files"
%w(file1 file2 file3).each do |name|
  system %(php #{DIR}/#{name}.php > #{DIR2}/#{name}.htm)
end
```

Can someone tell me how to make it so it will automatically find any .php files in the main directory and look in any defined folder and their sub-folders for additional .php and save them in similar folder names?

For example:

```
file1.php -> file1.htm
about-us/file2.php -> about-us/file2.htm
contact-us/department/file3.php -> contact-us/department/file3.htm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`Dir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#M000629):

```
Dir.chdir('where_the_php_files_area')
Dir['**/*.php'].each do |php|
    htm = 'where_the_html_files_should_go/' +  php.sub(/\.php$/, '.htm')
    system("php #{php} > #{htm}")
end
```

The `**` pattern for `Dir.glob` (AKA `Dir[]`) matches directories recursively so `Dir[**/*.php]` will give you all the PHP files under the current directory.

Comment: Thanks! So if I wanted to exclude a directory like "includes" (and possibly others), how could I do that?

Comment: @Cofey: The easiest way would be to add an `if(i_like_this_path(File.dirname(php))` check inside the block. [`File.dirname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M000027) will give you the directory part of the filename and you'd have to supply something sensible for `i_like_this_path()`.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: Leave my indentation alone please. I find the Ruby standard of two spaces to be completely unreadable and I have just as much attitude about it as the Ruby community :)

Comment: @mu is too short, I finally got around to trying your script and it doesn't seem to be going into sub-folders to search for .php files. It's only creating .htm files in the main directory. Any ideas?

Comment: @Cofey: Is it not finding all the PHP files or is it botching `htm` path? The `Dir['**/*.php']` should find all the PHP files under the current directory. What does `Dir['**/*.php'].inspect` have to say when you're in `irb` in the correct directory?

Comment: Here's an example: in the main directory, I have two files, test1.php and test2.php as well as files in sub-folders like contact-us (test3.php), about-us/ (test4.php). After the script runs, I only have two htm files (test1.htm and test2.htm). I also need the sub-folders and .htm files in addition to the main directory. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Cofey: Given your directory structure, `Dir['**/*.php'].each{|php|htm = php.sub(/\.php$/, '.htm');system("touch #{htm}")}` leaves me with these files: "about-us/test4.htm, about-us/test4.php, contact-us/test3.htm, contact-us/test3.php, test1.htm, test1.php, test2.htm, test2.php". Is that not what you're after?